# Representing dynamic Euller-Bernoulli beam matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I represent in matlab the left matrix dynamically, allowing me to grow it iterative for a given n.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `n`, the following code constructs the matrix you show, provided the pattern stays the same.

```
n = 5;
d(n) = -12;
d(1) = 12;
d(2:end-1) = 6;
b1(n-1) = 6;
b1(1:end-1) = -4;
b2(n-2) = 4/3;
b2(1:end-1) = 1;
a1 = b1(end:-1:1);
a1(1) = -a1(1);
A = diag(d) + diag(b1, -1) + diag(b2, -2) + diag(a1, 1) + diag(b2(end:-1:1), 2)
```

Output for `n=5`:

```
A =

   12.0000   -6.0000    1.3333         0         0
   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000         0
    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000
         0    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000
         0         0    1.3333    6.0000  -12.0000
```

Output for `n=8`:

```
A =

   12.0000   -6.0000    1.3333         0         0         0         0         0
   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000         0         0         0         0
    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000         0         0         0
         0    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000         0         0
         0         0    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000         0
         0         0         0    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000    1.0000
         0         0         0         0    1.0000   -4.0000    6.0000   -4.0000
         0         0         0         0         0    1.3333    6.0000  -12.0000
```

---

To use the sparse representation for `A` you can use pass to the command `spdiags` four arguments:

1. A matrix `B` whose columns are the diagonals of `A`.
2. A vector `d` such that `d(j)` is the diagonal in `A` whose elements will be filled with the elements in `B(:,j)` (the j-th column of `B`).
3. The number of rows in `A`.
4. The number of columns in `A`.

I use names that start with `a` (above) for super-diagonals and names that start with `b` (below) for sub-diagonals (I don't use `u` (upper) and `l` (lower) because l looks a lot like 1 in my editor). Here is the relevant code.

```
n = 8;
d(n, 1) = -12;
d(1) = 12;
d(2:n-1) = 6;
bb1(n, 1) = 0;
bb1(n-1, 1) = 6;
bb1(1:n-2) = -4;
bb2(n-1:n, 1) = 0;
bb2(n-2, 1) = 4/3;
bb2(1:n-3) = 1;
aa1 = bb1(n:-1:1);
aa1(2) = -aa1(2);
aa2 = bb2(n:-1:1);

// Sparse A
As = spdiags([bb2 bb1 d aa1 aa2], -2:2, n, n);

// Double-checking: converting As to a full matrix should give back A as constructed by the previous method.
A - full(As) // should be the zero matrix
```

Comment: how can I use spdiags to generate it to be more efficient in case of big n ?

Comment: @IulianRosca Please have a look at the addition to the answer.